# Custom User Sessions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication

I'm trying to make a stripped-down user sessions system, and tried to model it to be similar to authlogic.

```
class UserSession
  attr_accessor :username

  def initialize(params={})
    @username = params[:username]
  end

  def new_record?
    true
  end

  def self.find
    return nil if session[:username].nil?
    UserSession.new session[:username]
  end

  def save
    session[:username] = username
    session[:username] == username
  end

  def user
    User.find :first, :conditions => { :username => username }
  end

  def destroy
    session[:username] = nil
  end
end
```

I know there's no passwords or anything, but let's put that aside for the moment. My problem is that apparently it is not easy to and bad form to access the session from a model. Which leads me to wonder, how exactly am I supposed to abstract creating user sessions as a model, if I can't access the session?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally what I'd do is create a SessionsController, that manages the state of the UserSession (attributes, handling the authentication through the model, etc) and uses the sessions from the app:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  def new; UserSession.new; end

  def create
     @user_session = UserSession.new(params)
     if id = @user_session.user
       session[:current_user] = id
       redirect_to session[:last_url]
     else
       session[:current_user] = nil
       render :action => new
     end
  end

end

def destroy
  session[:current_user] = nil
  redirect_to root_path
end
```

A helper ( `def current_user; session[:current_user]; end` ) could also help. Basically the UserSession allows you to use form_for and similar helpers and act as a authentication strategy holder (when you implement).

Hope this can help you get started :)

Comment: This is similar to what I ended up changing it too, and it works fairly well; at this point I'm just curious how Authlogic manages to do it, since it doesn't seem like they're placing any logic in the controller.